# How to use Firebase Auth for different user groups with different requirements

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, verification, user-data

I´m currently working on an androidapp that uses firebase for authentification and storage of userdata. Users can have a different "status" what allows them to use other parts of the app. To keep my user data structured I would prefer to use different Autentification databases for different user groups if thats possible? Otherwise what options do I have with firebase to solve the problem?
Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Firebase project has a single store of users.

Since all it does is store the credentials for the user, there isn't a need for multiple lists in Firebase Authentication itself.

If your application needs to distinguish different types of users, you can:

1. Store those lists of users elsewhere, such as in one of the Firebase databases. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682346/how-to-store-data-in-firebase-along-with-authentication-data).
2. Store a custom claim in each user's profile to indicate the list(s) they belong to. For documentation, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).
3. Set up different projects, one for each type of user.

I've put these in order of most common to least common, so you might want to study and consider them in that order.