# How to allow only users of type admin to login in my react website using firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a login page that only a user of type admin can access. I have a field in my user's collection called level, and if the level is equal to admin the user should be able to log in otherwise they cant.

here is what I have tried so far but it is not working properly.

is there a better way to achieve what I require, or can my method be improved to be working properly? how can I query and authenticate the admin user using firestore?

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [adminEmail,setAdminEmail] = useState("")
  const [adminPassword,setAdminPassword] = useState("")
  const [adminFBEmail,setAdminFBEmail] = useState("")
  const [adminFBPassword,setAdminFBPassword] = useState("")
 
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("Users").get().then((adminSnapshot) => {

      adminSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if(doc.data().level != "admin"){
          alert("not admin")
        }else{
          setAdminFBEmail(doc.data().email)
          setAdminFBPassword(doc.data().password)
        }
      
    })
  })
},[]);

const handleSubmit = () => {
    if(adminEmail == adminFBEmail && adminPassword == adminFBPassword){
      alert("Admin logged in")
      navigate('/app/dashboard', { replace: true });
    }else{
      alert("error")
    }
  }


return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Login | Power Cargo</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'background.default',
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          height: '100%',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              email: '',
              password: ''
            }}
            validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
              email: Yup.string().email('Must be a valid email').max(255).required('Email is required'),
              password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required')
            })}
            onSubmit={() => {
             
            }}
          >
            {({
              errors,
              handleBlur,
              handleChange,
            
              isSubmitting,
              touched,
              values
            }) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <Box sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
                  <Typography
                    color="textPrimary"
                    variant="h2"
                  >
                    Sign on the internal platform
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
                <TextField
                  error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
                  fullWidth
                  helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
                  label="Email Address"
                  margin="normal"
                  name="email"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={(e)=> {
                    setAdminEmail(e.target.value)}}
                  type="email"
                
                  variant="outlined"
                />
                <TextField
                  error={Boolean(touched.password && errors.password)}
                  fullWidth
                  helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
                  label="Password"
                  margin="normal"
                  name="password"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={(e)=> {
                    setAdminPassword(e.target.value)}}
                  type="password"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
                <Box sx={{ py: 2 }}>
                  <Button
                    color="primary"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    fullWidth
                    size="large"
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                  >
                    Sign in now
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please please please don't implement your own email+password check, as there are dozens (if not hundreds) of pitfalls and you're likely hit many of them if you've never done this before. Instead use a dedicated provider for that - such as the one in [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth).

You can then still store the information about what user is an Admin in your Firestore database, but you'd do that by associating the user's ID (the UID from Firebase Authentication) with a role in the database. For more on this type of system, see some of the previous questions on the topic:

- [Separate Users and Sellers in the same app with same Firebase in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822406/separate-users-and-sellers-in-the-same-app-with-same-firebase-in-flutter)
- [How to create different user groups in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255622/how-to-create-different-user-groups-in-firebase)
- [How to give different access to different type of user for login in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907879/how-to-give-different-access-to-different-type-of-user-for-login-in-firebase)
- [How to use Firebase Auth for different user groups with different requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58412286/how-to-use-firebase-auth-for-different-user-groups-with-different-requirements)

Comment: can admin auth work with firestore?

Comment: What is "admin auth"?

Comment: the admin auth API https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin

Comment: Ah. Yes, custom claims that you set on the user token with the Admin SDK will show up in the `request.auth.token` in Firestore security rules (after up to an hour).